# Воспроизводить видео в WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

После того как добавил превьюшки видео в список
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу реализовать по их нажатию открытие в WebView. Создаю в методе `getView` - OnClickListener, и, в зависимости от position **стараюсь**("получить ссылку на видео") и затем открывать это видео в WebView. Но почему то открывается белый экран.
Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так(новичок).

Код `onClick` в `adapter`'e:

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ImageUpload imageUploads = new ImageUpload();
                intent.putExtra("video_link", imageUploads.getUrl());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Код `VideoActivity`:

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video_web_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String videoLink = extras.getString("video_link");

            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            });
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(videoLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Почти на 100% уверен, что проблема в получении ссылок, так как каждый элемент в частности, содержит ссылку на видео, но возможно я и ошибаюсь. Открыт для правок.

Comment: Если в конструкторе без параметров класса `ImageUpload` не инициализируется то, что отдает метод `getUrl()`, то и передано ничего не будет (точнее говоря, будет передано это самое `ничего`).